# Referring to a specific instance of a common noun

Tags: nouns, proper-nouns

Let's say I am planning an as of yet unnamed wall at the back of my garden, which I will build using gabion baskets.

If I temporarily refer to the wall according to its construction, should I write it as "the Gabion Basket Wall", or should it be "the gabion basket wall"?

Comment: There's a problem here. On second reading, I realise that by 'as yet unnamed' you mean 'not as yet referred to'. I was wondering where you lived, and whether the wall was going to rival the famous one in China; 'naming' brings to mind the Queen splashing the 'Ark Royal' with champagne. // Capitalisation is not used except in special cases. There are/have been a few named walls ('named' [and 'unnamed'] in the usual 'dubbed' sense), the Great Wall of China, the Berlin Wall, the Antonine wall .... Capitals are used for these, always. But for a common-or-garden wall, only if there are other ...

Comment: reasons for using them (if you have a title in an autobiography you're writing or under a photograph, say). Why did you think you might need capitals for the first mention?

Comment: No reason for the capitals.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. No, I really did mean “unnamed” as in we haven’t decided what to call it yet, though “not as yet referred to” might have been more accurate for the purposes of this question. The reason I thought you might use capitals was because I was referring to a specific instance of a hypothetical wall, which we (I.e. the builders and I) are already aware of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to name it according to its construction, it would be the second. However, if you are later going to refer to it as a unique entity (with a formalised name), I would recommend using the first upfront to make readers aware that this is a proper noun you are referring it to by.

Comment: Yes. It's like the difference between the white house (a house which is white) and the White House (a specific building).